# Check if ZK Window has focus

Tags: java, zk

How can I check if a `Window` has currently the "focus"?

i.e. check if it has the highest ZIndex. I can use `getZIndex()` but then I still don't know if it is the highest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can know a window become the top most one while onClick and onMove,

e.g.,

```
<zk>
  <window mode="overlapped" title="win one" border="normal" width="200px" height="150px">
    <attribute name="onMove"><![CDATA[
      ((Label)self.getFirstChild()).setValue("My Zindex is the highest one");
      ((Label)self.getNextSibling().getFirstChild()).setValue("");
    ]]></attribute>
    <attribute name="onClick"><![CDATA[
      ((Label)self.getFirstChild()).setValue("My Zindex is the highest one");
      ((Label)self.getNextSibling().getFirstChild()).setValue("");
    ]]></attribute>
    <label value="" />
  </window>
  <window mode="overlapped" title="win two" border="normal" width="200px" height="150px">
    <attribute name="onMove"><![CDATA[
      ((Label)self.getFirstChild()).setValue("My Zindex is the highest one");
      ((Label)self.getPreviousSibling().getFirstChild()).setValue("");
    ]]></attribute>
    <attribute name="onClick"><![CDATA[
      ((Label)self.getFirstChild()).setValue("My Zindex is the highest one");
      ((Label)self.getPreviousSibling().getFirstChild()).setValue("");
    ]]></attribute>
    <label value="" />
  </window>
</zk>
```

Comment: But what happens when the top most windows is closed, minimized etc.?

Comment: No easy way, need to get all window and compare there zIndex